# Extend JSON Server Data Provider in React-Admin so the update do not send the ID in the body

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin for the first time.
When updating (PUT) my backend do not accept the ID in the body (the reference for the id is in the url: [http://api.com/item/{id}](http://api.com/item/%7Bid%7D)).

But by default react-admin sends it.

How can I change that? I tried to extend the data provider, but I don't know how to make it modify the body:

```
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://localhost:8000', httpClient);

const myDataProvider = {
    ...dataProvider,
    update: (resource, params) => {
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }
            )).catch(err => {
            return console.log(err)
          })
        console.log(params.data);
    },
};

export default myDataProvider;
```

I think I would need to change the `params.data`, deleting the "id", but I couldn't... always get errors.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove it from the data:

```
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://localhost:8000', httpClient);

const myDataProvider = {
    ...dataProvider,
    update: (resource, params) => {
        const { id, ...data } = params.data;

        // don't forget to return the promise!
        return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }))
        .catch(err => {
            return console.log(err)
         })
    },
};

export default myDataProvider;
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. Is this line where you remove it from data?
 `const { id, ...data } = params.data;`

Comment: I don't know much JS, thanks, now I found that you do a destructuring assignment (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)